# Java "member reference"

Tags: java, lambda, java-11

Does Java have something analogous the succinct method reference syntax?

E.g., imagine I have:

```java
class Foo {
  public int getX() { ... };
  public int getY() { ... };
  public int getY() { ... };
}
```

I might write some generic code to handle all of these methods equivalently using method references, e.g.,:

```java
void printOne(String name, Function<Foo, Integer> extractFn) { .... };

printOne("x", Foo::getX);
printOne("y", Foo::getY);
printOne("z", Foo::getZ);
```

So far so good.

Now if instead of getters I had a simple POD like:

```java
class FooPod {
  public int x, y, z;
}
```

Is there any equivalent way to use something succinct like `FooPod::x` without needing to write out the whole lambda each time?

Comment: I guess you could write helper methods that give you the lambda, e.g. `class FooPods { static int x(FooPod f) { return f.x; } }`, then use `FooPods::x`. But short of that, you've got to write the lambda.

Comment: () -> x seems pretty succinct to me.

Comment: You could use a `record`. Or Lombok.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect `FooPod::x` to do? Seems like it's just giving you `FooPod.x` so just do that?

Comment: Is there a programming language you are referring to?  What is a _"succinct method reference"_?  Is it related to the _[succinct data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure)_?

Comment: Is `Foo::x` so much better than `foo -> foo.x` (or `f->f.x` if brevity matters that much)? Besides, you probably want to use `ToIntFunction<Foo>` instead of `Function<Foo, Integer>`.